Spring boot can't receive upload File form PostMan
try to use postman to upload a file and catch it on spring boot Controller
like below
postman setting
receive file on spring boot (version 1.5.6)
@RestController
@Path("/UploadFile")
public class UploadFileRsource {
    @Autowired private AmazonS3Service AmazonS3Service;

    @POST
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Path("/DrugProcessStepUpload")
    @ResponseBody
    public String DrugProcessStepUpload(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
            ) throws Exception {
        TransportUtil TransportUtil = new TransportUtil();
         return TransportUtil.genWebServiceReturnJsonString();
    }
}


but for now postman only get 404 not found，but if I change RequestParam data type form MultipartFile to String，it work and get result below
result
look like spring boot read file as string，can't understand what is wrong.
is MultipartResolver not working? how do i fix it?
upload png result
png result

I think it's because of Jersey.
Try to use FormDataMultiPart to receive the upload file and it should work.
